# Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zza found in modules

Tags: android, firebase

Just started this error on Android build. Please help.
"Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zza found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-19.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)"

Answer (score 16):

In build.gradle:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0"
```

Comment: This might work but it's not optimal. Version 2.2.0.0 has breaking changes and it's recommended to  fix the issues rather than adding this dependency. They removed the deprecated FirebaseInstanceId and replaced it with Firebase installations. https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#messaging_v22-0-0

Answer (score 6):

None of the answers above is correct. And none of them solves the problem.
The problem is in transitive dependencies.
You need to check which libs are causing the issue and do something like:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this problem by using the [Firebase Android BoM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more#bom)

In my case the problem depends on the coexistence of **messaging** and **functions**.

So from this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions-ktx:20.0.0'
```

To this:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.1')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
```

Comment: I am using version `31.0.0` of BoM and still having the issue.

Comment: Same to me, I use 31.0.2. @X09 did you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

**BOM 31.x** does have currently this problem.

**See issue here:**
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/4206

**Resolved via issue here but not yet official released:**
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/pull/4225

**Comment:**
*it was not resolved yet, 31.0.1 only contained a fix to crashlytics crash bug. That's why this issue is still open. The team here will make a fix close the issue, then do a release likely with release notes indicating it is fixed, when it is fixed https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android - here*

A **current workaround** is to add the iid version explicitly until a new BOM version is released:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.0')

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem.

I fixed it by redefining my dependencies implementations like this:

---

In build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'
```

---

Please note my configuration in buildscript: com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1

Then, clean and rebuild project.

Can you share more information about your setup?

Comment: I updated all firebase npm modules to the latest and fixed the issue. Packages are "messaging", "IId", "dynamic-links" and "app"

Answer (score 2):

Using react-native-push-notification ^3.1.9, I've got the same error.

To fix it :

in project/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "17.0.0"
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "20.1.0"
        firebaseVersion = "20.1.0"

        // other settings
    }
 // other settings
}
```

in project/app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0"
    // other implementations
}
```

The reason : `react-native-push-notification` package specify dependency to `firebase-messaging:+` : which ask to get the last version.
So, gradle upload the latest `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.x.x` which declare already existing classes in firebase-iid.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `firebase-bom` because you don't trust firebase to keep all the proper versions in check then you can remove the duplicate.

1. Run `./gradlew app:dependencies` (or replace `app` with your module)
2. Search for `iid:19.0.0` (or whatever version is giving you issues)
3. Scroll up in the list to see where the library originates from.

You should see something like `\--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0`

4. Keep scrolling until you find the dependency and module it originates in, marked with a `+` eg (`+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision`)
5. Locate the dependency in your project and remove the duplicate `iid`

```
api("com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:$version") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-iid'
}
```